# Php - Which button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, forms, button

I am writing a script where I provide two buttons "Grant" and "Revoke" to the user. The problem is that both of them are set and "Grant" button always takes precedence.

Below is Sample code

```
<form name="form_access" id="form_access" action="" method="POST" class="access">
|
|
| 

<input type="hidden" name="accessaction" value="Grant Access"/>
<input type="hidden" name="revokeaction" value="Revoke Access"/>

<a id="_access_btt" class="button" href="#">Grant Access</a>

    <img class="ajaxload" style="display:none;" id="ajaxld" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
    <a id="_revoke_btt" class="button" href="#">Revoke Access</a>

    <img class="ajaxload" style="display:none;" id="ajaxld1" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean "both are set"?

Comment: Could you link to the actual code that you are using?  This isn't enough to troubleshoot with.

Comment: @Gordon: I meant when you do isset on both variables it shows set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using two hidden elements, Why dont you use a single hidden element, something like this?

for example: you could use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="accessPermission" value=""/>
```

and depending upon what button user clicks, with the help of javascript you could set this action's value too:

```
document.form_access.accessPermission.value = "Revoke Access"
```

and

```
document.form_access.accessPermission.value = "Grant Access"
```

and then submit the form!

so in the end, you can just check value $_REQUEST['accessPermission'] in your PHP,

and you will get whatever value you have set for your hidden form element accessPermission:

if its value is Revoke Access you will get $_REQUEST['accessPermission'] as 'Revoke Access'

if its value is Grant Access you will get $_REQUEST['accessPermission'] as 'Grant Access'

So at the end, you can construct your form as:

```
<form name="form_access" id="form_access" action="" method="POST" class="access">
|
|
| 

<input type="hidden" name="accessPermission" value=""/>

<a id="_access_btt" class="button" href="javascript:document.form_access.accessPermission.value = 'Grant Access'">Grant Access</a>

    <img class="ajaxload" style="display:none;" id="ajaxld" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
    <a id="_revoke_btt" class="button" href="javascript:document.form_access.accessPermission.value = 'Revoke Access'">Revoke Access</a>

    <img class="ajaxload" style="display:none;" id="ajaxld1" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</form>
```

---

And Both the values are set because, its really specifically set by the lines:

```
<input type="hidden" name="accessaction" value="Grant Access"/>
<input type="hidden" name="revokeaction" value="Revoke Access"/>
```

Grant Action takes precedence, because that's appears first.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. However, when I click on the button it display Grant or Revoke Access. I wish to keep it on same page/work. I also tried to point to some test.php by adding action=test.php in the form and printing $_REQUEST but same behaviour. Could you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="accessaction" value="Grant Access"/>
<input type="submit" name="revokeaction" value="Revoke Access"/>
```

To check if Grant Access was pressed, you can check `isset($_POST['accessaction'])`.
To check if Revoke Access was pressed, you can check `isset($_POST['revokeaction'])`.

All browsers will only set the button that was pressed, IE is stupid and sets the value to the coordinates or something, other browsers set it to true, and Firefox usually sets the value to the t4ext on the button.  But the best way is to just check the `$_POST` array for which one is present.

### EDIT

Using JS to solve this might be okay, but this solution works when users have JS on or off and therefore I think it is more elegant

### EDIT

If you do not want to use these as actual buttons, you can set them to `display: none` then trigger a click on the one you want to actually submit the form.